# How to make div with 100% height of scrollable area

Tags: css

I have a div container with fixed height. That div has some content inside which makes it scrollable. I need to insert few divs inside that container and make them 100% height of scrollable area. How can I do that?

Here is the example:

```css
header {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;

  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  
}

.event {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 92px;
  background: rgba(200,0,0, 0.05)
}

.event-2 {
  transform: translateY(100%)
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="event event-1">1</div>
    <div class="event event-2">2</div>
</header>
```

I need to make green boxes full height of a scrollable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Javascript, an elegant solution is :

```
let headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').scrollHeight ;
let grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid') ;


for (let i = 0; i < grid.length ; i++){
  grid[i].style.height = headerHeight + 'px' ;
}
```

As we need to catch the total scroll height, this can't be done in full CSS without changing the DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the height of the grid to the value you want and use

```
.grid{
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: You have mentioned about the height and write code about overflow..